# negation of statement with "at least"

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

The negation of the following sentence:

**At least one girl has bought her friend a book, which she hasn't read herself.**

I have tried to write it with logical symbols

p = at least one girl has bought her friend a book

q = she has not read the book herself

so would the negation be $\lnot( p \land q)$, and this would be $\lnot p \lor \lnot q$?

but how could I say it in english?

would the negation of "at least" be "All girls....?"

Comment: Yes. "At least one..." means exactly the same thing as "there exists".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question, yes.
$\lnot(p \land q) = \lnot p \lor \lnot q$.

To answer the second, think when "at least one girl has blah" is true. Is it true when $0$ girls have blah? Is it true when $1$ girl has blah? Is it true when $2$ girls have blah?

Since "at least one girl has blah" is true for $\geq 1$ girls, the only time it fails is when $0$ girls have blah. So that's the negation.

As mentioned in the comments, you may notice that "at least one" is the same thing as "there exists". So if you know that
$\lnot \exists x \varphi = \forall x \lnot \varphi$, you can do this slightly quicker.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: thank you so much, so that means the second part of the sentence won't be affected by the negation at all? we negate only the first part (At least one...),  or is the part with "hasn't read the book herself" implicitly touched since "0 girls have given a book which they haven't read themself" the same as "All girls have a given a book which they have read themselves"?

Comment: If $p(g)$ means "girl $g$ has bought her friend the book", and $q(g)$ means "girl $g$ has read the book", then your sentence of interest is $\exists g . p(g) \land \lnot q(g)$. (Do you see why?). Then the negation is $\lnot \exists g . p(g) \land \lnot q(g)$, which we can simplify to $\forall g . \lnot (p(g) \land \lnot q(g))$, and simplify further to $\forall g . \lnot p(g) \lor q(g)$ (again, do you see why?). Then we can translate this back to english, and we are done

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed help, these were perfectly clear to me, the only part which I am having difficulties with is how to translate this $\forall g.\lnot p(g) \lor q(g)$ back to english, would it be: For all girls g ($\forall g$) it holds that no girl has given her friend a book ($\lnot p(g)$) or has read the book ($q(g)$)? I am confused by the $\lor q(g)$ part.

Comment: You're close! But rather than "no girl has given her friend a book", you want "$g$ has not given her friend the book". That's why we quantified over $g$.

Comment: thank you for your fast answer! :) so it would be "g has not given her friend the book" or has read it herself?

Comment: you've got it! ^_^

Comment: Perfect! thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

First part of your questions is by De Morgan’s law. And second part is also correct. “At least one girl did something” is equivalent to saying that “there exists a girl who did something”. The negation of “there exists” is “for all”.

Comment: thank you, so could I say "All girls have a given a book which they have read themselves" ?